# Vuforia with Video

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, htc-vive

I'd like to use Vive front camera for traking. but I'd don't know how to apply vive texture to ARcontroller in Vuforia.

So, I though that if there is a method to match video texture to ARcontroller, Vive texture could be matched also.

I use Unity program.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front facing camera support was added to SteamVR - you can also see: 
https://github.com/dariol/ViveTrackedCameraUnity and related blog for info on getting to the texture which you can pass into Vuforia.

Comment: but, Vuforia said that they only support cam texture, not video texture...

Comment: It's Texture2D here in this case (using OpenVR APIs not video or cam textures)